# How do I get my button to stay below my display on smaller screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

I want my jumbotron to have some reactivity when moving to smaller screen sizes. On md, lg, xl, I want my paragraph to stay on screen but at sm, xs, I want just the display-1 and button to appear. There is no issue at xs size but at sm the button goes inline. Thoughts on fixing this?

EDIT: (rephrase) I have 3 elements stacked in a column and centered in my jumbotron (h1, p, button). I would like my header and my button to appear at all screen sizes but have the p d-none when sm or xs. This works fine. However, at sm and md screen sizes, as the paragraph no longer displays, by button shifts inline and doesn't stay beneath my h1. How can I keep them stacked in a column? Thanks.

```css
.jumbotron {
 background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531346618680-ab17d6dcd07c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<section class="mx-0">
 <div class="container-fluid px-0">
  <div class="jumbotron mx-0">
   <div class="row justify-content-center pt-5">
    <h1 class="display-1">Welcome!</h1>
    <p class="lead text-center d-none d-sm-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas dapibus, ligula at luctus mattis, mauris nulla pharetra tortor, sit amet.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-md">More about me!</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your requirements. Can you elaborate (or rephrase) to better explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sounds like you want a hide `p.lead` for small screens? You can use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the upper class position : relative and the button class position: absolute